# Save uploaded image in project folder in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to save my uploaded image in project folder. but It getting saved in **Inventory\bin\Debug\assets** bin folder of my project.

Purpose of saving image in folder, as I want to save only image name to db, when I need to show image, Then I can get from folder like `/assets/xyz.png`

Here is my code to save image,

```
private void btnUploadLogo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();

            op.Title = "Select a picture";
            op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
              "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
              "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
            if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + @"\assets\";
                var fileNameToSave = DateTime.Now.ToFileNameFormat() + Path.GetExtension(op.SafeFileName);
                var imagePath = Path.Combine(appPath + fileNameToSave);

                if (!Directory.Exists(appPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
                }

                File.Copy(op.FileName, imagePath);

                imgUpload.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));
                panelImg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
```

As I want to save `assets/xyz.png` in my DB.

Comment: Do you want to save the image file in the same location where exe available?

Comment: @AnkurTripathi : I mean, There is folder inside project named `assets`.  I want to save it to that location.

Comment: you mean _Inventory/assests.._

Comment: @RahulAgarwal : Yes

Comment: You should not save any files in (or relative to) the executable's directory, as your application may not have write permission. Instead, save files in a subfolder under [`Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Clemens : Can you please explain this to me. Where those files will be saved when I'll use `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` and how?

Comment: Did you read the documentation linked in my previous comment? `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` usually returns `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: `var imagePath = Path.Combine(appPath + fileNameToSave);` ??? Either `var imagePath = appPath + fileNameToSave;` or `var imagePath = Path.Combine(appPath, fileNAmeToSave);`

Answer (score 0):

private void btnUploadLogo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();

```
        op.Title = "Select a picture";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
          "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
          "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + @"\assets\";
            var fileNameToSave = DateTime.Now.ToFileNameFormat() + Path.GetExtension(op.SafeFileName);
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(appPath + fileNameToSave);

            if (!Directory.Exists(appPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
            }

            File.Copy(op.FileName, imagePath);

            imgUpload.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));
            panelImg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }`private void btnUploadLogo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();

        op.Title = "Select a picture";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
          "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
          "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + @"\assets\";
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(appPath + op.SafeFileName);

            if (!Directory.Exists(appPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
            }

            File.Copy(op.FileName, imagePath, true);

            imgUpload.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));
            panelImg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```